# Create a grid using HTML and Jquery with out using plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Selecting the value of the grid and that should be appear in the grid row

Comment: Create a table and style the borders with css.

Comment: Grid is usually a `<table>` and I'm not sure what is it that you're asking here.

Comment: with out using table. how can i create a grid

Comment: Why not use a table? It _does_ make sense here.

Comment: @Chinnu, I don't know why you don't want to use a table, but you can use divs and spans.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for those old-fashioned things called tables.

Comment: @gdoron can u show me any eg

Comment: @Chinnu. Google can do it even better than me.

Comment: My goal is that when I select a value in the drop down it should  display in the grid.

Comment: for that to happen you should use AJAX

Comment: With out using ajax can I do this?

Comment: please edit and change your question with this information, what you really need is when you select a value in dropdown box, that value to appear in a html grid table row without submitting the page or rather ask a new question

Comment: OK you can do this without AJAX as well, we usually use AJAX for these things

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19319/discussion-between-chinnu-and-swarnajith)

Comment: -1 Can't tell what you're asking for, where is the question? What features do you want? why not use existing plugins? Where does the data come from? Is the grid bound to data? Please be more careful and detailed when asking questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,

**JQuery code**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectbox').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('.changedValue').html(val);
        });
    });                
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<form>
    <select name="selectbox" id="selectbox">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<table width="400" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Changed Value</td>
        <td class="changedValue">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create grid with jQuery
Check below link for grid view with jQuery..

http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx

http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/

Comment: I think the third link is broken